# HTML tables structure when using php+mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to generate HTML- table using following code:

```
<?php
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select distinct concat(concat(order_no, '_'), sequence_no) from database 
where order_no LIKE 'M114244' and release_no = '1'");
oci_execute($stid);

$stid2 = oci_parse($conn, "select oper_status_code from database 
where order_no LIKE 'M114244' and release_no = '1' and operation_no = '22'");
oci_execute($stid2);
?>


<table style=" width: 60%; text-align: left; position: absolute; top:220px; left:440px; font-size: 10px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>ORDER</th></td><th>STAGE</th></td>
</td>
<?php
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH))) {
    
foreach ($row as $item) {
echo '</tr><td>'.($row[0]).'</td>';
}}
    
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid2, OCI_BOTH))) {
    
foreach ($row as $item) {
echo '</td><td>'.($row[0]).'</td>';
}}          
?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

[image: table]

For some reason I will get duplicate M-numbers, which I should't get but this is not the main question this time.  Maybe I will later on find out the reason for this. Please don't mind that Finnish language inside the table. I would like to echo this table with following structure:

[image: table2]

That way the state of different stages could be seen from table.
Get the picture from the problem?
Appreciated from all possible help and tips.

Comment: The HTML you're generating is broken. You're emitting spurious `</td>` tags, and no `<tr>` tags in the body of your table.

Comment: Could you please specify where are those mistakes?

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code. Instead, post the generated HTML and the desired HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select distinct concat(concat(order_no, '_'), sequence_no) from database 
where order_no LIKE 'M114244' and release_no = '1'");
oci_execute($stid);

$stid2 = oci_parse($conn, "select oper_status_code from database 
where order_no LIKE 'M114244' and release_no = '1' and operation_no = '22'");
oci_execute($stid2);
?>


<table style=" width: 60%; text-align: left; position: absolute; top:220px; left:440px; font-size: 10px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>ORDER</th></td><th>STAGE</th>
</tr>
<?php $orders= [];
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_BOTH))) {
  foreach ($row as $item) {
    $orders[] = ($row[0]);
  }
}
$i = 0;   
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid2, OCI_BOTH))) {
  echo '<tr><td>'.$orders[$i].'</td>';
  foreach ($row as $item) {
    echo '<td>'.($row[0]).'</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
$i++;
}          
?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can I ask more questions from you? After using your example I have received order numbers M114244_3, M114244_3 and M114244_1  to my table. Number 3 is printed double times and number 2 is missing totally.  Another thing is that oper_status_code should be printed only once by one M-number, now code gives total of six results to the table, means double results. Any help appreciated.

Comment: While this code may be useful to the OP, providing [additional context](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/90527) regarding why & how it works, and when it should be used will improve its long-term value by helping other readers.

Comment: @mkl13: Outside of asking for clarification, [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) shouldn't be used to ask additional questions. SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. If you have questions beyond what you originally asked, first check whether the question has already been asked, and post a new question if not.